# Unable to retrieve a textarea's value

Tags: jquery, textarea

I've constructed a basic `form` in which there are certain elements, one of which is a `textarea` element.
The whole form is enclosed in a `div`, and when the user clicks the submit button the form is hidden and the value of the `textarea` should be shown for review.

I am using jQuery to retrieve the data in the textarea, but have also tried without it but to no avail.
I have tried using `.text()`, `.val()` and `.html()`. None of which work, even though `.val()` should be.

Here's the script I'm currently using:

```
$(function(){
    var ptext = $('#post_text');
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        data = ptext.val();
        alert(data);
        $('#form_container').fadeOut('slow', function(){
               $('#status').html(data);
               return;
       });
       $('#status').fadeIn('slow');
       return true;
    });
});
```

...and the textarea from the form

```
<div id="post_box"><textarea id="post_text" name="text" class="full"></textarea></div>
```

Additonal info: I'm using CKEditor on the textarea, but I do not think it would cause any problems like this. Have also tested in IE8 and Chrome.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you getting an alert at all? (with no message?). Does the Javascript console (firefox) show any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's CKEditor that causes this. The textarea is not a textarea at all any more, it has been replaced by something else, probably an iframe. As the textarea doesn't exist any more, you can't use the `val` method to get it's text.

Use the `getData` method to get the text from the editor:

```
var data = CKEDITOR.instances.post_text.getData();
```

Answer (score 2):

It has to be because of CKEditor, because your [**code for grabbing text from textarea is valid**](http://jsfiddle.net/balron/ekRMY/).